# Java Swing. Цыганские фокусы с раздвоением кнопки

Tags: java, swing

Если кратко то я создаю кнопку по нажатии которой в такт музыке должны создаваться рандомные прямоугольники. Все работает отлично, только кнопка двоится, даже если ее не нажимать а просто на нее навести. Скрины будут в конце. Объясните что происходит:)

Класс MiniMusicPlayer

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MiniMusicPlayer implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;
    static DrawPanel draw;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MiniMusicPlayer mMP = new MiniMusicPlayer();
        mMP.frame = new JFrame();
        draw = new DrawPanel();
        mMP.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mMP.frame.getContentPane().add(draw);


        JButton button = new JButton("Start/Stop");
        mMP.frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.AFTER_LAST_LINE, button);
        button.addActionListener(mMP);


        mMP.frame.setSize(300, 300);
        mMP.frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    public void go() {
        try {

            Sequencer squencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            squencer.open();

            int[] eventsWeNeed = {127};
            squencer.addControllerEventListener(draw, eventsWeNeed);

            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);
            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            for (int i = 5; i < 61; i += 4) {
                int rand = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                track.add(makeEvent(144, 1, rand, 100, i));

                track.add(makeEvent(176, 1, 127, 0, i));

                track.add(makeEvent(128, 1, rand, 100, i + 2));
            }


            squencer.setSequence(seq);
            squencer.setTempoInBPM(220);
            squencer.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        this.go();
    }


    public static MidiEvent makeEvent(int comd, int chan, int one, int two, int tick) {

        MidiEvent event = null;
        try {
            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(comd, chan, one, two);
            event = new MidiEvent(a, tick);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return event;
    }

}
```

Класс DrawPanel:

```
import javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements ControllerEventListener {
    boolean msg = false;

    @Override
    public void controlChange(ShortMessage event) {
        msg = true;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if (msg) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            int red = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            int blue = (int) (Math.random() * 250);
            int green = (int) (Math.random() * 250);

            g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));

            int ht = (int) ((Math.random() * 120) + 10);
            int weight = (int) ((Math.random() * 120) + 10);
            int x = (int) ((Math.random() * 40) + 10);
            int y = (int) ((Math.random() * 40) + 10);
            g.fillRect(x, y, weight, ht);


            msg = false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну как, разобрался?

Comment: @Elena_Gnil к сожалению нет